# is there a possibility to rotate text in a tree (tikz)?

Tags: tikz-trees, rotating, tikz-qtree

Is there a possibility to make my tree a bit more well-arragend? At the moment I think, there is a lot of mess and you do not get which description refers to wich line and so on. I hope you understand what I mean. I thought to arrange it like on the photo but I do not get it (how to rotate the text, so that it is on the line). Is there someone who may help me? Thank you!!

[image]

```
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[dot/.style={inner sep=0pt,minimum size=10pt,fill=black,circle}, ring/.style={inner sep=0pt,minimum size=10pt,draw,circle}]


\node[dot,label=90:{Spieler 1}] (n11) at (0,0) {};

\node[dot,label=135:{Spieler 2}] (n21) at (-4,-1) {};
\node[ring,label=:{}] (n22) at (4,-1) {};

\node[dot,label=-90:{$(0,0)$}] (n31) at (-6,-4) {};
\node[ring,label=:{}] (n32) at (-2,-4) {};
\node[dot,label=-90:{$(-1,1)$}] (n33) at (2,-4) {};
\node[dot,label=45:{Spieler 2}] (n34) at (6,-4) {};

\node[dot,label=-90:{$(1,-1)$}] (n41) at (-4,-7) {};
\node[dot,label=-90:{$(-2,2)$}] (n42) at (0,-7) {};
\node[ring,label=:{}] (n43) at (4,-7) {};
\node[dot,label=-90:{$(0.5,-0.5)$}] (n44) at (8,-7) {};

\node[dot,label=-90:{$(1,-1)$}] (n51) at (2,-10) {};
\node[dot,label=-90:{$(0,0)$}] (n52) at (6,-10) {};



\draw (n11) -- node[label=135:{passen}] {} (n21);
\draw (n11) -- node[label=45:{drehen}] {} (n22);

\draw (n21) -- node[label=135:{passen}:sloped] {} (n31);
\draw (n21) -- node[label=45:{drehen}] {} (n32);
\draw (n22) -- node[label=135:{Schuss}] {} (n33);
\draw (n22) -- node[label=45:{kein Schuss}] {} (n34);

\draw (n32) -- node[label=135:{Schuss}] {} (n41);
\draw (n32) -- node[label=45:{kein Schuss}] {} (n42);
\draw (n34) -- node[label=135:{passen}] {} (n43);
\draw (n34) -- node[label=45:{drehen}] {} (n44);

\draw (n43) -- node[label=135:{Schuss}] {} (n51);
\draw (n43) -- node[label=45:{kein Schuss}] {} (n52);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need nodes, for example `node[label=135:{passen}] {}` change with `node[above,sloped] {passen}`. With this you will get:

[image]

Complete code is:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,
               tikz,
               preview
               ]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
 dot/.style={circle, fill=black, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10pt}, 
ring/.style={circle, draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10pt}
                ]

\node[dot,pin=90:{Spieler 1}] (n11) at (0,0) {};

\node[dot,label=135:{Spieler 2}] (n21) at (-4,-1) {};
\node[ring] (n22) at (4,-1) {};

\node[dot,label=-90:{$(0,0)$}] (n31) at (-6,-4) {};
\node[ring] (n32) at (-2,-4) {};
\node[dot,label=-90:{$(-1,1)$}] (n33) at (2,-4) {};
\node[dot,label=45:{Spieler 2}] (n34) at (6,-4) {};

\node[dot,label=-90:{$(1,-1)$}] (n41) at (-4,-7) {};
\node[dot,label=-90:{$(-2,2)$}] (n42) at (0,-7) {};
\node[ring] (n43) at (4,-7) {};
\node[dot,label=-90:{$(0.5,-0.5)$}] (n44) at (8,-7) {};

\node[dot,label=-90:{$(1,-1)$}] (n51) at (2,-10) {};
\node[dot,label=-90:{$(0,0)$}] (n52) at (6,-10) {};

\draw (n11) -- node[above,sloped] {passen} (n21);
\draw (n11) -- node[above,sloped] {drehen} (n22);

\draw (n21) -- node[above,sloped] {passen} (n31);
\draw (n21) -- node[above,sloped] {drehen} (n32);
\draw (n22) -- node[above,sloped] {Schuss} (n33);
\draw (n22) -- node[above,sloped] {kein Schuss} (n34);

\draw (n32) -- node[above,sloped] {Schuss} (n41);
\draw (n32) -- node[above,sloped] {kein Schuss} (n42);
\draw (n34) -- node[above,sloped] {passen} (n43);
\draw (n34) -- node[above,sloped] {drehen} (n44);

\draw (n43) -- node[above,sloped] {Schuss} (n51);
\draw (n43) -- node[above,sloped] {kein Schuss} (n52);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @hpz1719, you are welcome. Is my answer useful for you? If it is, you can vote or even accept it :-)

Comment: of course i will do that : )

Comment: May I ask you another thing? Is there also a possibility to reduce the height of the font on the line? So I would not have to draw such a big tree...

Comment: You can .. meanwhile I sow your new question and answered it. Hopeful, I understand it correctly :-)